# Loop of activities and how to restrict them

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity

I am facing issue of looping between older activities, to explain it further I have: 
`Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3 -> Activity4 -> Activity5 ->` send mail.

User can go back multiple times to `Activity4` by keydown and again come back to `Activity5` and send mail. Further it creates two/multiple copies of activity4 and user has to press back key to close the activity. i want activity to be available only one time. I got this fixed by using `onpause` finish call till `Activity 5`. but as sending e-mail intent throws me out of app and as i finished all activites `on pause` I am not able to come back in app can any one help me with this please....

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getdata();

        String message = message
                ;
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "google@gmail.com" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."),1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent Act2Intent = new Intent(New.this, Old.class);
        startActivity(Act2Intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent Act2Intent = new Intent(New.this, Older.class);
            startActivity(Act2Intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }
```

Comment: Dont not use finish();  Activity5 , instead of using finish while creating use add these two flags to new acitvity to kill all other acitvities. 

Act2Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     
Act2Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: bobby ji mujhe ye mehod use karna nahi aata kya aap ye code me edit karke post kar sakte ho thanks monika

Comment: @user3058783 Try to Communicate in Common Language English.

Comment: i am trying flag method please wait for update

Comment: @user3058783 posted the code in answer as you require, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `finish();` in `Activity5`.

instead of using `finish`, while creating `activity` always add these two flags to new `activity` to kill all other activities.

```
Act2Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
Act2Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

That will not create two/multiple copies of activities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `launchMode` attribute of the `Activity` you are starting to `singleTop`. This will cause incoming Intents to be delivered to the existing instance rather than starting a new instance when that Activity is already at the top of the task's stack.

This is done in the `manifest` by adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the `<activity>` element

Avoid `finish()` in `onPause()`

Refer the document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode